# wrong classification with imagenet

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, vgg-net, imagenet

I have used VGG16 and imagenet weights to predict an image. But unfortunately, the prediction was wrong. 
I don't know where I went wrong.

Code:

```
from keras.preprocessing import image as image_util 
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import decode_predictions
from keras.applications import VGG16
import numpy as np 
import argparse
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i","--image",required= True,help ="path of the image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# orig = cv2.imread(args["image"]) #Opencv function to load a image

image = image_util.load_img(args["image"],target_size=(224,224))
image = image_util.img_to_array(image)

#print("!!!!!.....!!!!")
print(image.shape)

image = np.expand_dims(image,axis=0) #(224,224,3) --> (1,224,224,3)
#print("!!!!!.....!!!!")
print(image.shape)
image = preprocess_input(image)

#Loading the model 
model = VGG16(weights="imagenet")
pred = model.predict(image)
#print("111!!!!!.....!!!!")
#print(pred)
p = decode_predictions(pred)
#print("222!!!!!.....!!!!")
#print(p)

for (i,(imagenetID,label,prob)) in enumerate(p[0]):
    print("{}. {}: {:.2f}%".format(i+1, label, prob*100))


orig = cv2.imread(args["image"]) #Opencv function to load a image
(imagenetID,label,prob) = p[0][0]
cv2.putText(orig, "Label:{},{:.2f}%".format(label,prob*100),(10,30),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.8,(0,255,0),2)
cv2.imshow("classification",orig)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output:

The output must be an apple. But I got Granny smith

[image: Output predicted image]

Comment: have you tried some other images?

Comment: It works on other images. But fails on all apple images

Comment: try to use a crop image

Comment: Actually I tried 5 different types of apple image. Wrong every single time. Is  there any way to retrain only apple ? without lossing the old weights?

Comment: This is not really wrong as Granny Smith is in fact an apple.

Comment: @TA Oh! But, Granny smith are green apples. But do check the output image. Which of it is a red apple!

Comment: Maybe you do not have any trained label for the kind of apple you are interested in and this is as close as it gets.

Comment: Labels and weights are from Imagenet.